# Update a User Control from MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf

First, see this code in the MainWindow

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" MinWidth="900" MinHeight="650" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <local:RightSideContent x:Name="rightPanel"  Grid.Column="1"  Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>

    </Grid>
```

I create a User Control name RightPanel and name it in MainWindow.xaml *rightPanel*

Example, in the User Control RightPanel has a TextBlock name textblock.
Then, and I want to update the TextBlock and I am in MainWindow, I must call `rightPanel.textblock.Text ="..."`.

So I think it is not a good way, because if I am in another Class, so I can't go back to MainWindow to update this textblock, and I can't call a method(static or non) to MainWindow or to RightPanel to update. Once more reason I think it isn't good, anytime you must interactive the MainWindow, instead I think we should send directly the message to RightPanel.

Please help me, thanks and forgive if my English isn't clear enough!

Answer (score 3):

You can add a Dependency Property to your `RightSideContent` user control to handle the text.  This would let you bind to it directly from your `MainWindow`'s xaml.

The `RightSideContent` user control can then just bind the `textblock.Text` to that dependency property, displaying what's there.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a [Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) called "Text" and then bind it to a property on the MainWindow's DataContext.

Assuming you're not following the MVVM pattern, you would have some property in your MainWindow.cs, the code-behind. For example:

```
private string _rightSideText = string.Empty;
public string RightSideText
{
    get { return _rightSideText; }
    set
    {
        _rightSideText = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("RightSideText");
    }
}
```

This assumes you've implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your MainWindow.

Then, in your MainWindow XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" MinWidth="900" MinHeight="650" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <local:RightSideContent Text="{Binding Path=RightSideText}" x:Name="rightPanel"  Grid.Column="1"  Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
</Grid>
```

This assumes you've added the dependency property.

Once that's done, all you need to do is set the "RightSideText" whenever you want to change the text.